# run php process in background, send email when finished

Tags: php, apache, openstack

I am writing a script that allows users to download vm-images from a remote repository. The images have to download from the remote repository (a), to a local server(b), and then the users can download the image from that local server(b) via a url link. This is achieved via a php exec call on an api with url endpoints.

The question I have, is that it can take a while for the image transfer from the "a" machine to the "b" machine. Is there a way to  have the download process execute in the background. When image transfer is done, user gets an email containing the link to the file?

Otherwise, the user will just sit at a spinning page for as long as the max_execution_time setting will allow.

I was looking [at this site for reference](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/to-run-php-code-in), but it was not super helpful.

**Edit:** I am running on a LAMP setup

Comment: sure, you can exec an external script to do the fetching, put it into the background with `&` (assuming you're on a unix-y host), and then that external job can do the fetching/email without being tied to the foreground browser stuff.

Comment: That link looks helpful, what have you tried?

Comment: So just make the mailing part happen later in the same function call, and tie that function call to a process?

Comment: Have you ever heard of Ajax?  Its asynchronous.

Comment: Have you heard of using Ajax to call a php function, to run an exec command, to a glance API to download an 80gb file? .. Yes I've heard of Ajax

Comment: @developerwjk There is no need of Ajax. Shell scripts can silently do their job in background once triggered. Even though if you have closed the current page.

Comment: @Ryan, I meant that Ajax would call the php that builds the file and ultimately sends the email with the link. Because its asynchronous, the user isn't stuck waiting; and the server keeps processing the request even if the user closed the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into starting a worker via beanstalk.

http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/

You send a message containing the download link, and the email to send to. A worker can be started on demand when your message is sent, and automatically start the download. When the download is complete, your worker would fire off the email.

The PHP library to allow you to interface with beanstalk can be found here:

https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk

Answer (score 0):

### [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/)

Beanstalkd is a daemon written to handle running jobs asynchronously so that your user is not left hanging while waiting for a task to finish. It's written in Ruby (I think), but there are many client libraries to interface with it.

### [Pheanstalk](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk)

Pheanstalk is the PHP library for integrating with Beanstalkd. You can define `Job` classes and then use this API to submit those jobs for processing.

Most major frameworks have support for something like this.